# CakePHP Persistant Data Storage without Database (config file)?

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications, web, web-config

I am building a CakePHP app and I want to store and modify a group of global settings that are customisable by the admins. There is only one shared instance of these settings so a single row in a database seems like an overkill and doesn't feel right. I was thinking a config file would be more apt and was looking at CakePHP's Configure::read and Configure::write methods but the latter method doesn't persist the changes to the config file.

Are there any other appropriate or widely used methods? Or should I just use a table with a single column (which the OCD in me really doesn't want to do!)

Comment: why not seralize an array and put into a file

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP can write changes to a file, default reader is called PHPReader which reads from php config files.  Just have to make sure to use the expected formatting.  Once you load the config file you can use the read and write functions you listed above to change values, and then just dump the changes after finishing.

```
// Load my_config.php using the 'default' reader object.
Configure::load('my_config', 'default');

// Dump values into 
Configure::dump('my_config.php', 'default');
```

Comment: If you used my suggestion to solve your problem a correct answer check would be awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

You should check out a [Redis store](http://redis.io/). It's basically the equivalent of a key-value pair config file but it is stored in a type of database, so it is accessible from anywhere in case you need to scale. It's super fast, too.

I find that it's generally not a good idea to keep mutable config data in a file since it presents tons of problems when you want to scale your app to more than one server.

Answer (score 1):

Applications tend to get more settings as you add features, so I usually plan ahead and rather than make a table with a column for each setting the application has at the time, then adding columns as more settings are added, make a table to store settings as unique setting name and value pairs: `create table settings (id  int unsigned primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255) unique not null, value varchar(255) not null)`.  So for each setting, you have a row in your database.